# C++ Dynamic ND Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem creating ND arrays dynamically.
So for example:

```
int **A = 0;
A = new int *[rowsA];

for (int i=0;i<rowsA;i++) {
    A[i] = new int[columnsA];
    for(int j=0;j<columnsA;j++) {
            cout << "Enter " << "(" << i << "," << j << "): ";
            cin >> A[i][j];
    }
}
```

And passed to a function like: print_matrix(&A[0][0],rowsA,columnsA);

```
void print_matrix(int *A, int x, int y) {
     for (int i=0;i<x;i++) {
         for (int j=0;j<y;j++) {
                cout << A[i+j*x] << " ";
         }
         cout << ",";
     }
}
```

For example:

input : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

output: 6-digitnumber 6-digitnumber 4,2 6-digitnumber 5,3 6-digitnumber 6

any ideas?

Comment: Side notice : Shouldn't you `cout << A[i*y+j] << " ";`(outputs '1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9') instead of `cout << A[i+j*x] << " ";` (outputs '1 4 5, 2 5 8, 3 6 9')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by a ND array you mean an [Iliffe vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliffe_vector), you aren't building it correctly.  The data has to be allocated consecutively and thus in one allocation as the memory returned by successive calls to new isn't necessarily consecutive.  This should do the work:

```
int **A = new int *[rowsA];
int *data = new int[rowsA*columnsA];

for (int i=0;i<rowsA;i++) {
    A[i] = data + i*columnsA;
    for(int j=0;j<columnsA;j++) {
            cout << "Enter " << "(" << i << "," << j << "): ";
            cin >> A[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your A variable is an array of *pointers* (and each pointer points to a sequence of `int`'s) - `print_matrix` expects a pointer directly to a sequence of `int`'s. The two types are not compatible.

You'll need to either make print_matrix take an `int **`, or change the use of your A variable to be `A[i+j*x]` rather than `A[i][j]`

Comment: It's most unfortunate that some teachers make a distinction between a "real multidim array" and an "array of arrays", where they say the latter is an array of pointers. That makes people think that a "real multidim array" wouldn't be an "array of arrays", while in fact they are exactly that.

Comment: @litb, with my Ada background, I tend to think that there is no multidimentional arrays in C and C++.